# Is there a name for removing half of a doubly linked list edge?

Tags: java, c++, c, doubly-linked-list

Note: This isn't specific to Java/C/C++, but linked lists being as common as they are, I opted to tag it under those languages as well as doubly-linked-lists. If that's wrong, I can change it!

Let's say you have a standard doubly link list implementation:

```
struct List {
    int Number;
    struct List *blink;
    struct List *flink;
};
```

and that you have the following list:

```
1 <--> 2 <--> 3 <--> 4 <--> 5
```

Now, in my case, I've been using the `flink` as a terminator of sorts, and unlinking nodes in a single direction:

```
1 <--> 2 <--> 3 <--| 4 <--> 5
```

So 3's `flink` is `null`, but 4's `blink` points to 3.

(Mildly unrelated, I've been doing this to allow for quick modification and restoration of linked lists, and have things like:

```
1 <--> 2 <--| 3 <--> 4 <--> 5
         <--> 6 <--| 7 <--> 8
                <--> 9 <--> 10 <--> 11
```

to build a list of `1 2 6 9 10 11`)

My question is really just "does this type of operation have a well defined name?" I've been calling it "shearing", but if there's a real name that'd be nice to know.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list#Asymmetric_doubly-linked_list)?

Comment: @StackFlowed Or maybe http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Heron ohh thanks, I'll ask over there :)

Comment: @StackFlowed This question would be completely [off-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) at SuperUser.  Please check what's on topic at a site before suggesting people ask their question there!

Comment: @Heron Please explicitly advise people to flag for migration. Newer users don't realise it exists and we end up with multiple copies of questions around the SE network, which is against site policy and wastes people's time.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks. I'm pretty new here as well and I have yet to post a question, so I don't know what the OP can and cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

It is a kind of messy thing with doubly linked list. It is basically deleting nodes in an improper way.

Why I am saying it improper is, consider nodes 2 & 6, 2's `flink` is null and 6's `blink` points to 2.

By this you are telling 2 is the last node and 2 is in the back of 6. This is contradiction.

Where do you need this kind of approach?

Comment: I'm trying to optimize some graph traversal code that needs to visit every possible path. There's a decent amount of data that once generated will be constant for the node it's related to, and rather than regenerate it every time I hit the node, I want to generate it once, then re-link my linked list as necessary since the data at any node is sensitive to data that's ahead of it in the list.

It's not a great explanation, I can't really find the right words to explain it :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless you're also saving the pointers to the nodes 3, 4, 5, 7, and 8 then this would be called a "memory leak".

i.e. allocated memory you no longer have a way of accessing and therefore freeing.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't make that clear. Definitely storing the pointers that get unlinked ;)

Comment: Although rafeek's answer is somewhat tongue-in-cheek, he does have a point: this kind of data structure seems very likely to lead to subtle bugs in your code.  As such, it probably doesn't have a name because it's not something that would be widely used.